# Activecell.end.offset issue vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba, I am creating a userform and working on the code associated with the "Okay" button. I want to check the empty fields in the userform then go to another worksheet, select the top cell (B3), and then fill the data in the blank cell below (B4), moving along the row until column O. I want it to do the same each time someone fills in the userform and clicks "Okay".

However, there is an error message highlighting the line

> Worksheets("Data_raw").Select
>       Range("b3").Select

. I tried to use another file and it is working I do not know why it is displaying as an error on this file :(.

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my code please?.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub CmdOKAY_Click()


    'check all the fields to see if they are empty


    If BoxRM = "" Then
                MsgBox "Select a Relationship Manager"

            End If

    If TextCompany_name = "" Then
                MsgBox " Enter a company name"

            End If


    If BoxCountry = "" Then
                MsgBox "Select a country"

            End If

    If BoxTransactions = "" Then
                MsgBox "Enter a volume for the transactions"

            End If

    If Btn_Yearly_Transactions.Value = False And Btn_Monthly_Transactions.Value = False Then
                MsgBox "Select a frequency for the volume of transactions inputted"

            End If

    If BoxPosition_Vol = "" Then
                MsgBox "Enter a volume for the positions"

            End If

    If Btn_Yearly_Positions.Value = False And Btn_Monthly_Positions.Value = False Then
                MsgBox "Select a frequency for the volume of positions inputted"

            End If

    If CheckBox_RP.Value = False And CheckBox_TP.Value = False And CheckBox_TE.Value = False Then
                MsgBox " Select at least one type of account"

            End If

    Worksheets("Data_raw").Range("b3").Select

    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = RM


    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = NameCo

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Pays

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = RepTrd

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = FreqYrTrd

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = OP

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = FreqYrOP

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = AvrgDays

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = AcRP

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = AcTP

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = AcTE

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = RP_Per

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = TP_Per

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = TE_Per


    'copy the formats from the row above
    Range("b4:o4").Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Unload Me
End sub
```

Comment: You have to make sure that sheet is activated before you can select a range on it. Not that you need to select it all here...

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 line before that line:

```
Worksheets("Data_raw").Activate
Worksheets("Data_raw").Range("b3").Select
```

Comment: thanks but once I have done that the following line ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select  is highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You can work directly with the object and make your code shorter and easier to read and debug by refactoring your code like what is below.

The other thing I thought worth pointing out is that if you intend for the code to not paste any data if one or any of your checks fail, you'll need to add an `Exit Sub` inside each `If` block. Otherwise, it will keep going and paste what is available each time the button is clicked.

```
Dim wsRawData as Worksheet
Set wsRawData = Worksheets("Data_raw")

With wsRawData

    Dim lNextRow as Long
    lNextRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    .Cells(lNextRow, 2).Value = RM
    .Cells(lNextRow, 3).Value = NameCo
    .Cells(lNextRow, 4).Value = Pays

    '... and so on

End With
```